# Unable to insert string into Oracle DB if it has carriage return/new line characters

Tags: java, string, oracle

I have a Java program which reads from the body of an email and inserts selected data into my Oracle 11g database.

However, I have found I am getting this error upon attempting to insert the string of data into my Oracle DB:

> ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

The database column is of type VARCHAR2(4000) and I do not wish to change the datatype.

I have set a character limit of 500, and if the string is longer than that, I'm using the `substring` method to cut the length of the string to 500. However, I've found that when the character limit is exceeded and I've used the substring method to cut it down to 500 characters, the ORA-01461 error appears if there is new line and carriage returns present in the string.

I tried removing the new line and carriage return characters but strangely this did not stop this error from occurring, even though when debugging I could clearly see that the \r and \n characters had been removed from the string:

```
if(myString.length() > 500)
{
    myString= myString.substring(0, 500);
}

// Remove any carriage return and new lines
myString= myString.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
```

When I exceed the character limit but there are no EOL or carriage return characters present in the string, it is inserted into the database with no issues. 
When I don't exceed the character limit but there is EOL or carriage return characters present, it will also be inserted into the database with no issues.

So the issue only seems to occurs when I exceed 500 characters for a string which contains EOL and carriage returns, even when I attempt to replace those characters before inserting into database.

I'm using a parameterised `PreparedStatement` to insert the data, something like this:

```
preparedStatement.setString(10, myString);
```

The SQL is something like this, col10 is the column I'm having a problem with (not real column names):

```
INSERT INTO myDatabase (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9,col10,col11,col12) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),SYSTIMESTAMP,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Does it have to be a LONG? Will a CLOB do? Or even a VARCHAR?

Comment: It's not a long, it's a VARCHAR(4000) column. I don't know why the error says it's a LONG column, when it is not.

Comment: If at all possible, I wish to avoid changing the datatype due to various complications.

Comment: Please show the INSERT statement and ALL the relevant java code.

Comment: And, finally, is it a VARCHAR(4000) or a VARCHAR2(4000) column?

Comment: VARCHAR2(4000) column

Comment: First do the replaceAll and then do the substring in that case you will have more texts. if(myString.length() > 500)
{
myString= myString.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
}

    myString= myString.substring(0, 500);

Comment: Is the column defined as 4000 bytes or 4000 characters? Do the emails that are a problem have a lot of multibyte characters, or are different emails in different character sets, to each other or to the database? The line breaks look like a coincidence.

Comment: Which character set does the DB use?  e.g.  7-bit ASCII or Unicode UTF-8?

Comment: US7ASCII is the character set (I just checked), which I assume is 7-bit ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the INSERT statement was also inserting the entire body of the email into another column (also VARCHAR2(4000)) of the database, without cutting down its size. So the error I was getting was nothing to do with parameter 10 in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR(4000) means it can store a 4000 bytes String, so depending on your encoding it can store 1000 lengh string (UTF-8) or more.

You can check the bytes lenght with

```
final byte[] utf8Bytes =string.getBytes("UTF-8") //depends on your encoding
System.out.println(utf8Bytes.length);
```

But Oracle with JDBC has a known bug with VARCHAR2(4000) : 
You can try to set this property to see if it can fix the problem

```
oracle.jdbc.RetainV9LongBindBehavior = true
```

If you want more informations about this fix : https://vsadilovskiy.wordpress.com/2007/10/19/ora-01461-can-bind-a-long-value-only-for-insert-into-a-long-column/

Comment: On entry to the system, byte size is 9570 for one example, after operating on the string, it's down to 300 bytes, which should be fine. I'll try setting that property and see if that resolves the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting this property failed to make a difference. My database is Oracle 11g